# How to configure restrictions with Unity dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using dependency injection with Unity in my ASP.Net web application.

Suppose I create a simple service called MyService implementing IMyService. I would configure it like this in my UnityContainer:

```
...
container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(container);
```

I can now use the service:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class A
    {
       private readonly IMyService _myService;

       public A(IMyService myService)
       {
          _myService = myService;
       }

       ...
    }
}
```

That works just fine!

But what if I want to limit, which classes are allowed to inject MyService? For example if:

- I only want to allow it to be injected by class A, but not class B.

or

- I only want to allow it to be injected into classes belonging to namespace MyApp?

Can this be done?

Comment: What should happen if class `B` declares a dependency of type `IMyService` in the constructor? Throw an exception?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Yes that would be ok.

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done in Unity. May I ask why do you need to do this?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Because I have some repository services which I want to make sure only are accessed from a specific class.

Comment: In my opinion, you should have complete control over the object graph of the application. This is why I think that DI containers is a bad idea. I suggest that you take a look at [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). With Pure DI, you create the dependencies and inject them manually. It is easier to make sure that `MyService` is not injected into `B` when you manually need to inject `MyService` into `B`. Take a look at this article for more details on Pure DI and how it helps: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1285/clean-composition-roots-dependency-injection

Comment: I disagree here with @YacoubMassad. It is actually much harder to do this kind of automated analysis when you build up the object graph by hand. However, I don't know whether it is possible to do this with Unity. I know you can do this kind of Object Graph analysis in Simple Injector though. Besides this, I find your restriction quite suspicious. Seems you are forcing a strict layered approach, while you don't apply simple code reviews.

Comment: Hello @Steven. What I am trying to say is that I am against automated wiring and therefore automated analysis of the object graph. With Pure DI, you don't need to analyze the graph because there is not any magic in wiring it. The developers would have manually created the specific dependencies and injected them into specific places and thus they don't need any automated verification (apart from automated testing of course).

Comment: @Yacoub what I think the OP wants is to do NDepend like analysis to verify the architectural constraints. He wants to verify whether the developers play by the rules. What I'm saying is that it's actually quete hard to verify this when doing Pyre DI, except of course when applying good old code reviews.